# Pandas apply sort_values on GroupBy object does not return a grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I don't understand why the following code is not working. I have the following dataframe:

```py
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(2, 9), (2, 0), (3, 15), (3, 8), (2, 28), (2, 15), (2, 10), (3, 9)], names=['A','B'])

values = [0.2719, 0.2938, 0.3281, 0.3310, 0.3323, 0.3640, 0.3647, 0.5218]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = values, index=ind, columns = ['values'])
```

[image]

applying a groupby sort_values doesn't do anything:

```py
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='values'))
```

[image]

Note that the values are already *globally* sorted.

Now when i just swap two rows, and thereby destroy the global prior sorting, then it suddenly works:

```py
df1 = df.iloc[np.r_[1,0,2:len(df)]]
df1.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='values'))
```

[image]

This is the result I would expect from the other code also.

Comment: I figured that simple operations like `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x:x)` don't created a grouped dataframe either. So maybe i just don't understand when groupby will reorder the resulting dataframe vs. when it won't.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say a great deal about the `combine` part of the `split-apply-combine` in the docs:

> GroupBy will examine the results of the apply step and try to return a sensibly combined result.

Since you're not changing the number of rows or their order in the first example, `apply` functions more like `transform` which returns a "like-indexed object".

I think if what you want is a nested sort, you can just pass a list to `sort_values` directly, like so:

```
df.sort_values(["A", "values"])
```

```
      values
A B         
2 9   0.2719
  0   0.2938
  28  0.3323
  15  0.3640
  10  0.3647
3 15  0.3281
  8   0.3310
  9   0.5218
```

Comment: For the sake of predictablilty I settled with the kind of code you quoted. What i do not understand is how groupby apply can be so erratic. I mean, now I know that it's a bad idea to do sorting in a groupby apply operation, because it produces unpredictable results. But what else can I not do with groupby apply that will screw me. I should maybe report this behavior to the pandas github group. In my opinion the behavior should be consistent. Both for cases when you give something sorted vs. not sorted and the case where you perform an index vs. column operation.

Comment: I mean think about it: When the dataframe is already globally sorted then no extra multiIndex column is inserted, but then it isn't you get the extra column. How can code deal with this? Essentially the code either has to check beforehand if the dataframe is already sorted, or it has to explicitly check for the a duplicated index level.